# Magento 2 Persistent Cart not working?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

When a user is logged in and then logs out I want his shopping cart to be transferred to his then guest account. And when the users is a guest, logs onto his account, that the cart it "copied" from the guest to the logged in user.

With my understanding of Magento 2's persistence module, it should work like that if under

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Persistance Shopping Cart

I only set "Clear Persistence on Sign Out" to NO..it should work that way.

But it keeps clearing the cart when I log out. I have changed settings in the cookies, with the idea that that wasn't setup properly, but it's not working.

Is my thinking off, or am I right and is something not working in M2?

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior for Magento to clear the cart when you **manually** log out.

However, if **the session expires** and the customer is automatically logged out, Magento will **retain the cart items**. Additionally, after the welcome message, the text "**Not you?**" will be displayed.

[image]

You can confirm this by setting the Cookie Lifetime to a short duration, such as 30 seconds. After logging in, if 30 seconds elapse, your account will be automatically logged out, but Magento will still retain the cart items.

Comment: Is there a way to have it persistent with a manual logout?

Comment: Yes. You can examine the `Magento_Persistent` and `Magento_Customer` modules, then implement your customization in your custom module.

Comment: I have checked and found that the `customer_logout` observers in the `Magento_Persistent` module are responsible for removing the persistent cookie and session when the customer logs out. You can disable these observers to keep persistence after the customer logs out. Please note that the `customer_logout` observers in the `Magento_Persistent` module are located in `frontend`, `webapi_rest`, `webapi_soap` areas (vendor/magento/module-persistent/etc), you will need to create an `events.xml` file in each area in your custom module to allow this customization work on all areas.